# Excessive "Unmanaged memory" consumed by dotnet 6

Tags: .net, .net-core, memory-leaks

After porting from dotnet 5 to dotnet 6 a backend application is consuming a lots of "unmanaged memory". It is a complex F# application hosted on Linux, runs multiple process, lots of serialization of messages from EventStore and have actor model implemented with AKKA.NET.

No major code changes during port.

#### Screenshot for dotnet 5

[image: dotnet 5 memory consumption]

#### Screenshot for dotnet 6

[image: dotnet 6 memory consumption]

The unmanaged memory can peak to 6 GB, and if process remains idle (no messages in EventStore) it releases some unmanaged memory and settles around 3-4 GB.

##### Other Details

- OS : Linux (Ubuntu 22.04, Debian 10.11)
- dotnet 6 Version : 6.0.401
- dotnet 5 Version : 5.0.408

Used `dotnet-dump` and also `dotMemeory` from JetBrains. (`dotMemory` does not provide any insights into "unmanaged memory"). Currently exploring WinDbg and dotnet-dump commands.

Help I am looking for is

1. How to probe unmanaged memory and pinpoint issues?
2. Any useful commands for WinDbg/dotnet-dump to analyze "unmanaged memory"
3. Possible reasons on why dotnet 6 needs so much unmanaged memory when dotnet 5 can do with a relatively low footprint.

Comment: I found `dotnet trace` quite useful to track the memory consumption on Linux, Many tools (dotnet dump, gcdump) were useful to debug managed memory but not that useful for unmanaged memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with Marten, The updated version (v3 -> v5) was creating types at Runtime and hence causing spike in unmanaged memory. Marten team explained the behavior [here](https://martendb.io/configuration/prebuilding.html). The issue resolved after following the instructions provided by Marten team.